# how to browse to website on the same machine it's hosted on with IIS 7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, localhost, bindings

I have 2 websites hosted on an IIS 7 server. I can browse (in Internet Explorer) to the 'Default Web Site' at `http://localhost` but I want to be able to do the same thing with the other website.

From what I can figure I think I need to edit the bindings for my website but I don't want to mess with it until I get some advice.

The website I want to browse to can be accessed from outside the localhost using a regular domain name. How can I access it from the same machine that's hosting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to create a friendly hostname in IIS for the site (mysite [without the  .com] fro example) and then make an entry in your hosts file (mysite 127.0.0.1)